# app not initializing with prod build after converting application from angular 8 to angular 9

Tags: angular, angular9

we have an existing application with angular 8. so now we are converting our existing application from angular 8 to angular 9. we have faced some issues while converting but all those errors got solved. we are not facing any issues with dev build but problem with production build. prod build was successful but while opening the application angular app is not initializing.here is 
my tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "noStrictGenericChecks": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

my angular.json is

```
 {
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "energyapp": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "ClientApp",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "styleext": "scss"
        }
      },
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "wwwroot",
            "index": "ClientApp/index.html",
            "main": "ClientApp/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "ClientApp/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "ClientApp/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "ClientApp/appResourceFiles",
                "output": "/wwwroot"
              },
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "ClientApp/appResourceFiles",
                "output": "/"
              },
              "ClientApp/desktopIndex.html"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "ClientApp/appResourceFiles/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": ["./node_modules/echarts/dist/echarts.js"]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [{
                "replace": "ClientApp/environments/environment.ts",
                "with": "ClientApp/environments/environment.prod.ts"
              }],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "ngswConfigPath": "ClientApp/ngsw-config.json"
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "energyapp:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "energyapp:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "build-worker": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-webpack:webpack",
          "options": {
            "webpackConfig": "./webpack.config.worker.js"
          }
        },
        "dev-worker": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-webpack:webpack",
          "options": {
            "webpackConfig": "./ClientApp/webpack.config.dev-worker.js"
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "energyapp:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "codeCoverage": true,
            "main": "ClientApp/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "ClientApp/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "ClientApp/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "ClientApp/karma.conf.js",
            "styles": [
              "ClientApp/appResourceFiles/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [""],
            "assets": [
              "ClientApp/favicon.ico",
              "ClientApp/assets"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "ClientApp/tsconfig.app.json",
              "ClientApp/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "desktop": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "ClientApp",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "styleext": "scss"
        }
      },
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "wwwroot",
            "index": {
              "input": "ClientApp/desktopIndex.html",
              "output": "index.html"
            },
            "main": "ClientApp/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "ClientApp/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "ClientApp/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "ClientApp/appResourceFiles",
                "output": "/wwwroot"
              },
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "ClientApp/appResourceFiles",
                "output": "/"
              },
              "ClientApp/desktopIndex.html"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "ClientApp/appResourceFiles/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": ["./node_modules/echarts/dist/echarts.js"]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "index": {
                "input": "ClientApp/desktopIndex.html",
                "output": "index.html"
              },
              "fileReplacements": [{
                "replace": "ClientApp/environments/environment.ts",
                "with": "ClientApp/environments/environment.prod.ts"
              }],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "ngswConfigPath": "ClientApp/ngsw-config.json"
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "energyapp:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "energyapp:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "build-worker": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-webpack:webpack",
          "options": {
            "webpackConfig": "./webpack.config.worker.js"
          }
        },
        "dev-worker": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-webpack:webpack",
          "options": {
            "webpackConfig": "./ClientApp/webpack.config.dev-worker.js"
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "energyapp:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "codeCoverage": true,
            "main": "ClientApp/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "ClientApp/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "ClientApp/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "ClientApp/karma.conf.js",
            "styles": [
              "ClientApp/appResourceFiles/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [""],
            "assets": [
              "ClientApp/favicon.ico",
              "ClientApp/assets"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "ClientApp/tsconfig.app.json",
              "ClientApp/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "energyapp-e2e": {
      "root": "e2e/",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "energyapp:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "energyapp:serve:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "energyapp"
}
```

my package.json is

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-webpack": "^0.901.7",
    "@angular/animations": "~9.1.2",
    "@angular/cdk": "^9.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "~9.1.2",
    "@angular/core": "~9.1.2",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "9.0.0-beta.31",
    "@angular/forms": "~9.1.2",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.16",
    "@angular/material": "^9.2.4",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^9.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~9.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~9.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^9.1.9",
    "@angular/router": "~9.1.2",
    "@angular/service-worker": "^9.1.11",
    "@capacitor/android": "2.2.0",
    "@capacitor/core": "2.2.0",
    "@datorama/akita": "^4.23.0",
    "@datorama/akita-ng-forms-manager": "^3.1.0",
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.6.1",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.28",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.13.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "5.26.0",
    "@ionic-native/file": "5.26.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "5.26.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "5.26.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "5.2.0",
    "@material-extended/mde": "^3.0.0",
    "@ng-select/ng-select": "^4.0.0",
    "@nguniversal/express-engine": "9.1.1",
    "@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader": "^8.2.6",
    "@ngx-loading-bar/core": "^4.2.0",
    "@types/mapbox-gl": "^1.10.2",
    "ajv": "6.12.2",
    "angular-resizable-element": "^3.3.2",
    "angular-tree-component": "8.5.6",
    "angular2-cookie": "^1.2.6",
    "angular2-draggable": "^2.3.2",
    "angular2-infinite-scroll": "^0.3.5",
    "angular2-text-mask": "^9.0.0",
    "applicationinsights-js": "^1.0.21",
    "bpmn-js": "7.2.0",
    "bpmn-js-properties-panel": "^0.33.2",
    "brace": "0.11.1",
    "bs-platform": "^7.3.2",
    "capacitor-sqlite": "~2.1.0-7",
    "cordova-plugin-file": "~6.0.2",
    "countries-and-timezones": "^2.2.0",
    "countrycitystatejson": "^0.2.15",
    "d3": "^5.16.0",
    "d3-tip": "^0.9.1",
    "date-fns": "^2.14.0",
    "echarts": "^4.8.0",
    "electron-dl": "^3.0.0",
    "electron-log": "^4.0.6",
    "electron-updater": "4.1.2",
    "electron-window-state": "5.0.3",
    "electron-window-state-manager": "0.3.2",
    "geojson": "^0.5.0",
    "getusermedia": "^2.0.1",
    "hammerjs": "2.0.8",
    "idb": "^5.0.4",
    "immer": "^7.0.0",
    "ion-rangeslider": "^2.3.1",
    "ionic-long-press": "2.0.3",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "json-logic-js": "^1.2.2",
    "jsonpath": "^1.0.2",
    "knex": "^0.21.1",
    "localforage": "^1.7.3",
    "mapbox-gl": "^1.10.1",
    "material-design-icons": "^3.0.1",
    "microsoft-cognitiveservices-speech-sdk": "^1.10.0",
    "mobx-angular": "^4.1.0",
    "moment": "^2.26.0",
    "ng-drag-drop": "^5.0.0",
    "ng-pick-datetime": "^7.0.0",
    "ng2-pdf-viewer": "^6.3.0",
    "ng2-popover": "0.0.14",
    "ng2draggable": "1.3.2",
    "ng4-click-outside": "^1.0.1",
    "ngx-color-picker": "^9.1.0",
    "ngx-file-drop": "^9.0.1",
    "ngx-quill": "^11.0.0",
    "ngx-scroll-event": "^1.0.8",
    "ngx-take-until-destroy": "^5.4.0",
    "ngx-web-worker": "^8.0.0",
    "node-gyp": "^7.0.0",
    "observable-webworker": "^3.2.4",
    "quill": "^1.3.7",
    "rebuild": "^0.1.2",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.1",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.5.5",
    "source-map-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "sqlite3": "^4.2.0",
    "timespan": "^2.3.0",
    "ts-xlsx": "0.0.11",
    "tslib": "2.0.0",
    "videogular2": "^7.0.2",
    "xlsx": "^0.16.1",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2",
    "zoomdata-client": "^5.8.0-6.20200609030059.b826d893.release"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.901.8",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "9.1.8",
    "@angular/cli": "~9.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "~9.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~9.1.2",
    "@angular/language-service": "~9.1.2",
    "@capacitor/cli": "2.2.0",
    "@compodoc/compodoc": "1.1.11",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "2.2.0",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "^9.1.8",
    "@types/jasmine": "3.5.10",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/jsonpath": "^0.2.0",
    "@types/mapbox-gl": "^0.51.4",
    "@types/node": "^12.12.6",
    "@types/selenium-webdriver": "^4.0.9",
    "@types/sqlite3": "3.1.6",
    "@types/three": "^0.103.2",
    "@types/xlsx": "0.0.36",
    "codelyzer": "5.2.2",
    "electron": "^8.3.1",
    "electron-builder": "21.2.0",
    "electron-rebuild": "^1.11.0",
    "electron-reload": "1.5.0",
    "http-server": "^0.12.3",
    "http-server-legacy": "^0.11.1",
    "jasmine-core": "3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "5.0.2",
    "karma": "5.0.9",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~3.3.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "1.5.4",
    "node-pre-gyp": "^0.15.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.13.0",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.3",
    "npm-upgrade": "^2.0.3",
    "npx": "10.2.2",
    "protractor": "7.0.0",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "sinon": "^9.0.2",
    "ts-node": "~8.10.2",
    "tslint": "~6.1.2",
    "typescript": "~3.8.3",
    "wait-on": "^5.0.1",
    "webpack": "^4.43.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.11"
  }
```

can any one know what the issue is?

**Update**
[image]

in console there was no error but npm audit we have few vulnerabilities.

**Updated Package.json**:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-webpack": "^0.901.7",
    "@angular/animations": "~9.1.11",
    "@angular/cdk": "^9.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "~9.1.11",
    "@angular/core": "~9.1.11",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "9.0.0-beta.31",
    "@angular/forms": "~9.1.11",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.16",
    "@angular/material": "^9.2.4",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^9.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~9.1.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~9.1.11",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^9.1.11",
    "@angular/router": "~9.1.11",
    "@angular/service-worker": "^9.1.11",
    "@datorama/akita": "^4.23.0",
    "@datorama/akita-ng-forms-manager": "^3.1.0",
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.6.1",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.28",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.13.0",
    "@material-extended/mde": "^3.0.0",
    "@ng-select/ng-select": "^4.0.0",
    "@nguniversal/express-engine": "9.1.1",
    "@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader": "^8.2.6",
    "@ngx-loading-bar/core": "^4.2.0",
    "ajv": "6.12.2",
    "angular-resizable-element": "^3.3.2",
    "angular-tree-component": "^8.5.6",
    "angular2-cookie": "^1.2.6",
    "angular2-draggable": "^2.3.2",
    "angular2-infinite-scroll": "^0.3.5",
    "angular2-text-mask": "^9.0.0",
    "applicationinsights-js": "^1.0.21",
    "bpmn-js": "7.2.0",
    "bpmn-js-properties-panel": "^0.33.2",
    "brace": "0.11.1",
    "bs-platform": "^7.3.2",
    "countries-and-timezones": "^2.2.0",
    "countrycitystatejson": "^0.2.15",
    "d3": "^5.16.0",
    "d3-tip": "^0.9.1",
    "date-fns": "^2.14.0",
    "echarts": "^4.8.0",
    "electron-dl": "^3.0.0",
    "electron-log": "^4.0.6",
    "electron-updater": "4.1.2",
    "electron-window-state": "5.0.3",
    "electron-window-state-manager": "0.3.2",
    "geojson": "^0.5.0",
    "getusermedia": "^2.0.1",
    "hammerjs": "2.0.8",
    "idb": "^5.0.4",
    "immer": "^7.0.0",
    "ion-rangeslider": "^2.3.1",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "json-logic-js": "^1.2.2",
    "jsonpath": "^1.0.2",
    "knex": "^0.21.1",
    "localforage": "^1.7.3",
    "mapbox-gl": "^1.10.1",
    "material-design-icons": "^3.0.1",
    "microsoft-cognitiveservices-speech-sdk": "^1.10.0",
    "moment": "^2.26.0",
    "ng-drag-drop": "^5.0.0",
    "ng-pick-datetime": "^7.0.0",
    "ng2-pdf-viewer": "^6.3.0",
    "ng2-popover": "0.0.14",
    "ng2draggable": "1.3.2",
    "ng4-click-outside": "^1.0.1",
    "ngx-color-picker": "^9.1.0",
    "ngx-file-drop": "^9.0.1",
    "ngx-quill": "^11.0.0",
    "ngx-scroll-event": "^1.0.8",
    "ngx-take-until-destroy": "^5.4.0",
    "ngx-web-worker": "^8.0.0",
    "node-gyp": "^7.0.0",
    "observable-webworker": "^3.2.4",
    "quill": "^1.3.7",
    "rebuild": "^0.1.2",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.4",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.5.5",
    "source-map-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "sqlite3": "^4.2.0",
    "timespan": "^2.3.0",
    "ts-xlsx": "0.0.11",
    "tslib": "2.0.0",
    "videogular2": "^7.0.2",
    "xlsx": "^0.16.1",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2",
    "zoomdata-client": "^5.8.0-6.20200609030059.b826d893.release"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.901.8",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "9.1.8",
    "@angular/cli": "~9.1.8",
    "@angular/compiler": "~9.1.11",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~9.1.11",
    "@angular/language-service": "~9.1.11",
    "@compodoc/compodoc": "1.1.11",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "^9.1.8",
    "@types/jasmine": "3.5.10",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/jsonpath": "^0.2.0",
    "@types/mapbox-gl": "^1.10.4",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@types/selenium-webdriver": "^4.0.9",
    "@types/sqlite3": "3.1.6",
    "@types/three": "^0.103.2",
    "@types/xlsx": "0.0.36",
    "codelyzer": "5.2.2",
    "electron": "^8.3.1",
    "electron-builder": "21.2.0",
    "electron-rebuild": "^1.11.0",
    "electron-reload": "1.5.0",
    "http-server": "^0.12.3",
    "jasmine-core": "3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "5.0.2",
    "karma": "5.0.9",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~3.3.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "1.5.4",
    "node-pre-gyp": "^0.15.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.13.0",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.3",
    "npm-upgrade": "^2.0.3",
    "protractor": "7.0.0",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "sinon": "^9.0.2",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~3.8.3",
    "wait-on": "^5.0.1",
    "webpack": "^4.43.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.11"
  }
```

Comment: Try to `ng update` to the latest angular packages, current is `@angular/core": "~9.1.11`

Comment: Is there any console errors in browser.if not run npm audit. it will gives you the conflicts of the packages.

Comment: @CodeMind there was no errors in browser console.please look at screenshot above. i have updated my question

Comment: @HDJEMAI i have updated latest versions of angular9. but still facing same issue.

Comment: In chrome devtools, you might try to `pause on any exceptions`. That may help to find any non-displayed issue in the console. This will not guarantee to give any results since it will stop sometimes at non useful places for your issue.